# AngularJS set initial active class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using [Bootstrap tabs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) with an [Angular ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat).

The problem I'm running into is that the first `li` and the first `div.tab-pane` each need an active class. Bootstrap takes care of that *after* a tab is clicked but, as you can see, not on load.

My question is, how can I set an active class on the first `li` and `div.tab-pane`?

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/FQgHx/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All you have to do is put an `ng-class` directive on the tab and tab pane that you would like active initially.  You can change the expression from `$index == 0` in the ng-class directive to whatever you would like.  This could use a function or variable in your scope.

Here is a JS Fiddle showing how to do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/digitalzebra/qqPZd/

And here is the final code... notice the ng-class directives:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-init="names = [{name:'one'}, {name:'two'}, {name:'three'}, {name:'four'}, {name:'five'}]">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-repeat="name in names" ng-class="{active: $index == 0}">
      <a href="#tab{{$index + 1}}" data-toggle="tab">Week {{acute.Week}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab{{$index + 1}}" ng-repeat="name in names" ng-class="{active: $index == 0}">
      <p>{{$index + 1}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```